# How to check if a field is set to true in Mongoose model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to write a query string that only gets those values for which the "enabled" field in Mongoose model is set to true, but the query I've written doesn't seem to be working. It returns everything in the database, no matter what I change it to.

Tried variations of the query string.

```
const PostsSchema = new Schema({
title: String,
description: String,
enabled: {
type: Boolean,
default: true
}
});
```

Here is my query string:

```
query = { $and:[ {$text: { $search: search_string }},{"enabled":{$ne:false}} ] };
opts = { score: { $meta: 'textScore' } };
sort = {
     score: { $meta: 'textScore' }
};

let results = await Posts.find(query, opts)
        .sort(sort).lean();
```

Comment: You have written there `{"enabled":{$ne:true}}`  which means it only fetches those document where enabled: false but expecting documents where it is true. Please correct the query or update the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a function which fetches only enabled set to true in a collection,
this is one of the way to achieve.

```
db.posts.aggregate ([
    { $match: { enabled: true } }
    ]);
```

In aggregation, you can also sort, group, limit, skip the values.